# Domain of $f(x) = \log(\tan x - \sqrt{3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

This is my attempted solution for finding the domain of $f(x) = \log(\tan x - \sqrt{3})$:
$$
D(f)=\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
I got this answer by setting $\tan x  - \sqrt{3} = 0$ and knowing that the $\log$ can take negatives too. Would this be a correct way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because $\log$ cannot take in negative values if you want the output to be real. You need 
$$
\tan x>\sqrt{3}\implies \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi>x>\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi
$$
which makes your domain 
$$
\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \right)
$$

Comment: Why is it $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and not $\frac{\pi}{3}$